# How to manage user messages in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, properties, format

We store user messages in a properties file as *format strings* (e.g. `"Invalid parameter [%s]"`) and create actual messages in runtime. It is convenient since non-programmers can edit  the messages however it causes runtime exceptions if an arguments list does not match the format string.

Is there a "safer" solution with compile-time check in Java/Scala, which still allows non-technical people to create/edit user messages?

Answer (score 2):

The closest I've seen to compile time checking of resource bundles in Java is [cal10n](http://cal10n.qos.ch) but it's quite a bit of boiler plate per message and still doesn't verify the correct number of arguments.  It just guarantees that the keys are present really.

Perhaps your best bet might be to create a simple DSL using Scala?  I think this could allow your non-programmers to write message bundles that seem simple but are compiler checkable scala source.